# How to check if there is validation message for user then enter value in textbox and submit the form again else goto controller (in razor view)?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on busy icon(After clicking on submit button, show loading image  till the success page comes) in my MVC5 application.
This is my razor view :

```
<div id="Updatefeature">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateFeature", "UpdateFeature", FormMethod.Post))
        {
          <table>
            <tr>
                    <td><label>Feature Display Name:</label></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.m_feature.m_featDescription, new
                                    {
                                        @class = "form-control",
                                        @required = "required",
                                        @id = "FeatureDispName",
                                   })
                    </td>
              </tr>
             <td><input type="submit" value="Update Feature" id="UpdateFeature"      onclick="javascript: $('#LoadingDiv').show();"/></td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home", null, new
                                    {
                                        @class = "btn btn-primary"
                                    })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
</div>
```

This is my associated script :

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {           
            debugger;
            var datafromGrid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedGridItem"));

            $("#FeatureDispName").val(datafromGrid.Description);

            var wnd = $("#Updatefeature");          
            if (!wnd.data("kendoWindow")) {
                wnd.kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            title: "Update Feature",
            height: "500px",
            width: "500px",
            draggable: false,
            close: function () {
                        window.location = "/Home";
        },
            visible: true
        }).data("kendoWindow").center().open()
        }
        });
 </script>
```

Since I'm showing Busy icon (Loading div) on click of Submit button, my application is showing busy icon even if there is validation message(tooltip) for user that "Please fill out this field", which is my textbox in view marked as `"required"` field. So user can not enter the Feature Description even after the message is shown to user "Please fill out this field".

So my question is where I should put script code `"$('#LoadingDiv').show();"` in my view?

When user put "Feature Description field" as null and click on update feature, it shows busy icon with validation message. I want user to get validation message and allow him to re-enter that field and again click on Update feature button and proceed. But my View is showing busy icon with Kendo window as blur, so user can not enter any description, he can just keep clicking on button and get the validation error message. I've put break-point in controller method, but it is not coming to controller even, it gets stuck in the same view.
I've tried putting `"$('#LoadingDiv').show();"` on various events(lostfocus, on blur).
I've also tried

```
if ('@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "POST"')
        {
            $('#PageLoader').show();
        }
```

but nothing seems to work.
Is there any other way I can achieve showing loading icon in my application?